# Extending latency time in Leaflet.extras suspendScroll() command

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am using the **suspendScroll()** in leaflet.extras package to prevent my map from zooming while scrolling the browser. However, the latency — that is, the time it takes for the sleeping leaflet map to wake up upon hovering - of the function is too short. Is there a way to extend the latency time or make it in such a way that the leaflet map wakes up only if I click the map?

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

donkey <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  suspendScroll() %>%
  addMarkers(lng=-77, lat=38.89, popup="Washington D.C. Zoo")
donkey
```

Answer (score 2):

`leaflet.extra` documentation makes it clear, your options to use are the `wakeTime` and `hoverToWake` arguments. An example follows:

```
donkey <- leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  suspendScroll(wakeTime = 1000, hoverToWake = F) %>%
  addMarkers(lng=-77, lat=38.89, popup="Washington D.C. Zoo")
donkey
```

You can also set the argument `sleepTime` which might be quite useful.

Browse the docs for more info: `?suspendScroll`